# How to use piscope from my pigpio library on python

Tags: python, pigpio

I want install piscope for my raspberry by python but after I installed according to link http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html, I not know how call piscope and using it how? I do as @joan guide but it still be error. [image]

Comment: Which set of instructions from that page did you follow?  There are several, and based on this I'd guess you used the "Linux 64 bit X86/AMD (pre-built image)" ones (`make x86_64`), not the "Pi (pre-built image)" ones (`make hf`).

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for your answer. I have downloaded and installed piscope. from Pi (pre-built image)

Answer (score 5):

**If you are running piscope on a Pi enter the following commands.**

`sudo pigpiod # Start the daemon if not already running.`

`piscope & # Run piscope in the background.`

The main piscope display will be blank until there is GPIO activity.  You can trigger activity with the following command.

`pigs p 4 64 # Start 25% dutycycle PWM on GPIO 4`

`pigs p 4 0 # Stop PWM on GPIO 4`

**If you are running piscope on a networked Linux machine do the following.**

On the Pi.

`sudo pigpiod # Start the daemon if not already running.`

On the networked Linux machine

`export PIGPIO_ADDR=pi_host_name`

where `pi_host_name` is the network address of the Pi.

`piscope & # Run piscope in the background.`

The main piscope display will be blank until there is GPIO activity.  You can trigger activity with the following command (on the Pi or the networked Linux machine).

`pigs p 4 64 # Start 25% dutycycle PWM on GPIO 4`

`pigs p 4 0 # Stop PWM on GPIO 4`

Comment: it appear a error when I enter piscope on terminal: -bash: usr/local/bin/piscope: cannot execute binary file

Comment: @quyenhuynh Have you installed piscope? If so what error do you get?

Comment: I installed piscope as your guide at link: http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html

Comment: I installed piscope as your guide at link: http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html. I code raspberry on putty use SSH. I must enter "piscope & # Run piscope in the background. " is enter on terminal of raspberry?

Comment: @quyenhuynh You need to edit your question and explain what you have done, what you are trying to do, and what doesn't work.  I'm not going to guess.